# How can I make an ad Banner that can be closed with an x button?

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is what I tried, doesn't work. The result on my web page is a blank div at the bottom. I expected the css to darken the page when the ad shows up brighten when it is closed. But it doesn't.

```js
function adTimer() {
  setTimeout(banner, 5000);
}
var btn = document.querySelector('#btn-dismiss')
btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  bannerad = document.querySelector('#darken');
  bannerad.style.display = 'none';
  document.querySelector("html").classList.remove("darkenPage");
});

function banner() {
  btn.innerhtml = "x";
  bannerad.innerhtml = "Click here to go to our request page";
  document.Banner.src = 'images/banner.jpg';
  document.querySelector("html").classList.add("darkenPage");
}

var image = new image();
image.src = 'images/banner.jpg';
```

```css
html.darken {
  background-color: black;
}

html.darkenP body {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div align="center">
  <div id="banner-ad">
    <img width="400px" height="400px" style="border-radius:40px; font-size:40px;" name="Banner" />
    <button id="btndismiss"></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: well, if you run the snippet (or take a look at your console on your web page), you'll see that you have at least one error due to a typo: button id is `btndismiss` while you try to reach it in JS as `document.querySelector('#btn-dismiss')`

Comment: so have you tried to debug this further? What have you achieved? (There's at least one more error which is reported by console in your code)

Comment: I erased everything and started over. I learned what a modal is and used that concept. The solution i used, i put as an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I've started this over and got what I was looking for. This is JavaScript I used:

```
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
window.onload = function() {
  setTimeout(function (){modal.style.display="block";},5000);
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

This is html I used:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <h2>texxt</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>text</p>
      <p>text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <h3>footer text</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```